# Java strange variable assignment enquiry

Tags: java, variables

I've come across a weird situation. The code is as below:

```
public static int add(String trcd, String tlcd, String dept, String doDate,
                    String doTime, String andConfirm, Teller admin) throws
  Exception {

try {
  String table1 = "table1";
  String table2 = "table2";
  String trap = null;
  String trtype = null;

  String sql = "select * from " + table2;

  DataSet dataset = DBOper.DBQuery("taUtil", sql);

  if (dataset.isEmpty()) {
    return -1;
  }
  else {
    HashMap map = dataset.getRow(0);
    trap = (String) map.get("aut_ap_code");
    trtype = (String) map.get("aut_type_code");
    //point 1
    sql = "insert into " + table1 + " values("+trtype + "','" + doDate + "','" + doTime + "','N','Y')";

    DBOper.DBUpdate("taUtil", sql);

    if (andConfirm.equals("Y")) {
    //point 2
    sql = "select * " + table1 +" where tr_create_date='" + doDate + "' and tr_create_time='" + doTime + "' and tr_stcd='Y'";
      //point 3
      DataSet dataset2 = DBOper.DBQuery("taUtil", sql);

      if (dataset2.isEmpty()) {
        return -2;
      }
      else {
        String trNo = null;
        HashMap map2 = dataset2.getRow(0);
        trNo = (String) map2.get("tr_no");
        confirm(admin, trNo, "N");
      }
    }
    return 0;
  }
}
catch (Exception e) {
  throw e;
}
```

}

The problem is:

at point 3, it
always prints "insert" ie the previous sql value instead of the latest assignment of "select".

Does anybody knows why is it so ?
Thanks

Comment: Post code that reproduces the problem and everybody can compile it having JDK

Comment: Don't want to call you a liar, but it's hard to believe. Can you recompile this code and make sure you are running what you have posted here?

Comment: At the line `sql = "insert into " + ...`, the string starting with `" values ...` has unescaped quotes. How is the code even compilable?

Comment: I think it would be best to maybe break this down a bit more, comment out some of your code above that statement. Unfortunately, there is not enough here for any of use to run so that we may help you.

Answer (score 1):

You have a syntax error in your assignment statement:

```
sql = "insert into " + table1 + " values(trtype + "','" + doDate + "','" + doTime + "','N','Y')";
```

Try to replace it with:

```
sql = "insert into " + table1 + " values(" +trtype + "',' " + doDate + "','" + doTime + "','N','Y')";
```

I'm not sure how you even managed to compile this...

**EDIT:** If this syntax error does stop the code from compiling and your IDE (assuming you are using one) executes older version of the class that could not be compiled (has happened to me using Eclipse on occasions), I think it could end up doing something completely unpredictable and possibly explain this odd behavior.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel: You're probably right but I don't follow. I understand that the problem he is having is that it always prints "insert" instead of the newly assigned value, but isn't there syntax error in that line? I can't see how this code would compile and if it indeed doesn't and the old version is executed it could end up doing pretty much anything depending on the last version, right?

Comment: @OpDeCirkel  I disagree. This answer completely explains the phenomena. +1

Comment: @OpDeCirkel It is obvious that he isn't executing that source code at all, he is executing an older version of the class, as this poster suggested above.

Comment: Hi all, the syntax error of the "sql" assignment is a typo (I remove those sensitive sql statements), but it shouldn't distract the focus from the assignment problem I've encountered. It's not a cache class problem. I use eclipse debugger to print out all varibles values and examine the printouts. I just cannot post an image here...anyway, I am so frustruated at this. It's radiculous. Maybe the answer is simple but I just do not know at the moment. Any one knows ? Thanks.

Comment: @joy The reason is given both in this answer and in the comments above. You aren't running the code you think you are running.

Comment: @OpDeCirkel In that case I suggest your comments are now superfluous and should be deleted. I will follow suit.

Comment: At point 3, the "sql" stores "insert..." but not "select..." as expected. Do you know why ?